# How do I remove the orange color that covers the mesh whenever I highlight the octahedral bones

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, mesh, rigging

I can't arrange the bones on the mesh properly whenever I highlight the octahedral bones because of the orange color coming from the bone, please how do I remove it.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please use https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/, not your phone camera

Comment: I havent seen anything like that before ... graphic card issue? OS specific bug? BTW Under Win10 you can use shortcut Win+Shift+S for screenshot.

Comment: If I highlight a B bone or octahedral bones that orange outline comes out